# disable button in js

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am making a clicker game
And I needed to stop the button from clicking when the player bought the button's thing.
so i tried

```js
var money = 10000000;
var MoneyperClick = 1;

function myFunction() {
  var val = document.getElementById("YourMoney");
  val.innerHTML = money;
  document.getElementById("YourLevel").innerHTML = MoneyperClick;
}

function
upgrade(up, need) {
  if (money >= need) {
    money = money - need;
    MoneyperClick =
      MoneyperClick + up;
    alert("구매 성공");
  } else {
    alert("골드 부족");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <h1>MERVEL CLICKER GAME</h1>
    <br/>
    <input id="special" type="button" value="click" onclick="money = money+MoneyperClick; 
myFunction();" />
    <br/> STARLORD:money per click +1:need 100 money
    <input class="normal" id="starlord" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(1,100); myFunction();" />
    <br/> BABYGROOT:money per click +2:need 150 money
    <input class="normal" id="babygroot" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(2,150); myFunction(); " />
    <br/> MANTIS:money per click +2:need 300 money
    <input class="normal" id="mantis" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(2,300); myFunction();" />
    <br/> NEBULA:money per click +2:need 400 money
    <input class="normal" id="nebula" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(2,400); myFunction();" />
    <br/> HAWKEYE:money per click +3:need 700 money
    <input class="normal" id="hawkeye" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(3,700); myFunction();" />
    <br/> BLACKWIDOW:money per click +3:need 1500 money
    <input class="normal" id="blackwidow" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(3,1500); 
myFunction(); " />
    <br/>
    <h1>your money is <span id="YourMoney"></span></h1>
    <h1>your money per click is <span id="YourLevel"></span></h1>
    <h1> You can buy everything only once </h1>
```

My page in action: http://appletree-noamboy2006504805.codeanyapp.com/clicker.php

How can I disable the "buy" button if the item got purchased?

---

aha!
there was an disable property in buttons.
case solved.
thank's for everyone helped.

Comment: you really need to format and indent your code, this is so unreadable.. how are you working??!

Comment: Please, format your code. What you want to achieve is not that difficult, but with the current state of your question we can't help you.

Comment: how do i format? im korean  im not good at english

Comment: @김성훈 it's indenting your code by 4 spaces each level and every element belonging to a new line :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs formated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to disable the button that got clicked, pass the button (`this`) as parameter to your `upgrade()` function like this (simplyfied):

JavaScript: 
`function upgrade(up, need, button) { button.disabled = true; }`

HTML: 
`<input type="button" onclick="upgrade(1, 100, this)">`

```js
var money = 10000000;
var MoneyperClick = 1;

function myFunction() {
  var val = document.getElementById("YourMoney");
  val.innerHTML = money;
  document.getElementById("YourLevel").innerHTML = MoneyperClick;
}

function
upgrade(up, need, button) {
  if (money >= need) {
    button.disabled = true; // Added this line to disable the button that got clicked
    money = money - need;
    MoneyperClick =
      MoneyperClick + up;
    alert("구매 성공");
  } else {
    alert("골드 부족");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <h1>MERVEL CLICKER GAME</h1>
  <br/>
  <input id="special" type="button" value="click" onclick="money = money+MoneyperClick; 
myFunction();" />
  <br/> STARLORD:money per click +1:need 100 money
  <input class="normal" id="starlord" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(1,100, this); myFunction();" />
  <br/> BABYGROOT:money per click +2:need 150 money
  <input class="normal" id="babygroot" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(2,150,this); myFunction(); " />
  <br/> MANTIS:money per click +2:need 300 money
  <input class="normal" id="mantis" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(2,300,this); myFunction();" />
  <br/> NEBULA:money per click +2:need 400 money
  <input class="normal" id="nebula" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(2,400,this); myFunction();" />
  <br/> HAWKEYE:money per click +3:need 700 money
  <input class="normal" id="hawkeye" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(3,700,this); myFunction();" />
  <br/> BLACKWIDOW:money per click +3:need 1500 money
  <input class="normal" id="blackwidow" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(3,1500,this); 
myFunction(); " />
  <br/>
  <h1>your money is <span id="YourMoney"></span></h1>
  <h1>your money per click is <span id="YourLevel"></span></h1>
  <h1> You can buy everything only once </h1>
```

Comment: @김성훈 Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Use either
`document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;`
or

```
 var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

For to disable the button

```js
function disableBtn() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}

function enableBtn() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">My Button</button>
<br><br>

<button onclick="disableBtn()">Disable "My Button"</button>
<button onclick="enableBtn()">Enable "My Button"</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to use `<button>` tag instead of `<input>` tag.

```
<input class="normal" id="starlord" type="button" value="buy" onclick="upgrade(1,100);  myFunction();">
```

will become :

```
<button class="normal" id="starlord" onclick="upgrade(1,100);  myFunction(); this.disabled=true;">buy</button>
```

As you can see, I've added `this.disabled=true;` in the onclick attribute of the button. This way, it will disable itself on the first click.